# AWS CloudFormation: "The key pair ___ does not exist" error for newly-created EC2 key pair

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

I'm using a custom CloudFormation resource to generate an EC2 keypair for an automated install. I'm trying to remove as many manual steps as possible  for a highly-automated server setup. Here is the portion of the CloudFormation template with the relevant code:

```
LambdaRole:
  Type: AWS::IAM::Role
  Properties:
    AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
      Version: '2012-10-17'
      Statement:
        - Action:
            - sts:AssumeRole
          Effect: Allow
          Principal:
            Service:
              - lambda.amazonaws.com

LambdaPolicy:
  Type: AWS::IAM::Policy
  DependsOn:
    - LambdaRole
  Properties:
    PolicyName: CFNCustomSecretProviderPolicy
    PolicyDocument:
      Version: '2012-10-17'
      Statement:
        - Effect: Allow
          Action:
            - iam:CreateAccessKey
            - iam:DeleteAccessKey
            - iam:UpdateAccessKey
            - ssm:PutParameter
            - ssm:GetParameter
            - ssm:DeleteParameter
            - ec2:ImportKeyPair
            - ec2:DeleteKeyPair
          Resource:
            - '*'
        - Effect: Allow
          Action:
            - kms:Encrypt
          Resource:
            - '*'
        - Action:
            - logs:*
          Resource: arn:aws:logs:*:*:*
          Effect: Allow
    Roles:
      - !Ref 'LambdaRole'

CFNSecretProvider:
  Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
  DependsOn:
    - LambdaPolicy
  Properties:
    Description: CloudFormation Custom:Secret implementation
    Code:
      S3Bucket: !Sub 'binxio-public-${AWS::Region}'
      S3Key: lambdas/cfn-secret-provider-0.11.0.zip
    Handler: secrets.handler
    MemorySize: 128
    Timeout: 30
    Role: !GetAtt 'LambdaRole.Arn'
    Runtime: python2.7

PrivateKey:
  Type: Custom::RSAKey
  DependsOn: CFNSecretProvider
  Properties:
    Name: /mainframe/onyx-private-key
    KeyAlias: alias/aws/ssm
    ServiceToken: !Join
      - ":"
      - - arn:aws:lambda
        - !Ref "AWS::Region"
        - !Ref "AWS::AccountId"
        - !Ref CFNSecretProvider

CustomKeyPair:
  Type: Custom::KeyPair
  DependsOn:
    - CFNSecretProvider
    - PrivateKey
  Properties:
    Name: CustomKeyPair
    PublicKeyMaterial: !GetAtt
      - PrivateKey
      - PublicKey
    ServiceToken: !Join
      - ":"
      - - arn:aws:lambda
        - !Ref "AWS::Region"
        - !Ref "AWS::AccountId"
        - !Ref CFNSecretProvider

EC2Instance:
  Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
  DependsOn:
   - CustomKeyPair
   - InstanceProfile
  Properties:
    IamInstanceProfile: !Ref InstanceProfile
    InstanceType: !Ref InstanceType
    ImageId: !FindInMap [AWSRegionToAMI, !Ref "AWS::Region", AMI]
    KeyName: !Ref CustomKeyPair

...
```

Everything in this seems to work great up until the instance is created. It fails claiming the keypair doesn't exist, even though the keypair is there after it runs, and I can query it:

```
∴ aws ec2 describe-key-pairs --region=us-east-2 --profile=mainframe- 
personal
{
    "KeyPairs": [
        {
            "KeyFingerprint": "90:42:11:40:a5:9b:66:af:78:ce:b4:d1:54:07:95:27",
            "KeyName": "CustomKeyPair"
        },
        {
            "KeyFingerprint": "27:5c:bf:4a:b2:f6:75:3b:8c:c3:1b:57:0d:7e:28:de:8e:cd:90:69",
            "KeyName": "default"
        }
    ]
}
```

The error I'm getting in the CloudFormation event log is **The key pair 'arn:aws:ec2:us-east-2:685716241758:keypair/CustomKeyPair' does not exist**. That ARN is exactly what is shown in the resource list. Is there some reason that CloudFormation can't find this keypair?

Comment: Can you confirm there's no region conflict?

Comment: Keypair ARNs are `...:key-pair/...` rather than `...:keypair/...`, aren't they?

Comment: Are you passing the ARN? I guess it looks for the key with the ARN as its name. Can you try to pass just the key name `CustomKeyPair` instead of ARN?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [AWS::EC2::Instance - AWS CloudFormation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-instance.html#cfn-ec2-instance-keyname) documentation says:

> **KeyName:** Provides the *name* of the Amazon EC2 key pair.

The error message is suggesting that an **ARN** was passed. Instead, try just passing the name (the last part of the ARN).

Comment: This did work. I figured it out before seeing your answer. Thanks.